# Moving from QueueUserWorkItem to Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

.NET 4.5 and VS2012 are my targets

In my C# I have a lot of this old code:

```
var stuff;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
    {
          stuff=GetStuff():
           InvokeOnMainThread(stuff);
    });
```

How is this done with the new Task system in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would typically map to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     return GetStuff():                  
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // InvokeOnMainThread(t.Result); // Note that this doesn't need to "Invoke" now
    UseStuff(t.Result); 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // Moves to main thread
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5, you can also optionally mark the method `async`, and do:

```
var stuff = await Task.Run(() => GetStuff());
UseStuff(stuff); // Will be on the main thread here...
```

Comment: Why Task.Factory instead of Task.New?

Comment: @gleng There is no `Task.New` - You can use `Task.Run`, but only in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Doh, Task.Run is what I was referring to.

Comment: Forgot to mention .NET 4.5 and VS2012 are my targets

Comment: @gleng If the OP changes his question, please don't update the answers to match the new question. It would be okay to add the appropriate tag versions to the Question.

Comment: @dcaswell The edit was proper; the code sample following that statement wouldn't work in VS 2010, only 2012.  Reed clearly intended to write 2012, making it a valid edit.